# Update cURL without update Xampp

Tags: php, curl, xampp, exchangewebservices

I am working with Exchange Web Service (2007) using php-ews. Its dependencies say "cURL with NTLM support (7.23.0+ recommended)" but in the server we have an old Xampp with cURL 7.21 and my code doesn't work. In local I have cURL 7.42 and my code works perfectly. We have a lot of things in the server so Is possible update only the cURL library?? or use cURL from windows (CLI)??

Comment: Did you ever consider updating xampp ? If curl is old other components might be old too and expose you to security risks.

Comment: yes. I know. I consider that but the company doesn't want to update all the server yet because is a lot of data. Only cURL for that code.

Comment: Show us your code and someone might be able to tell you if and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was download the next portable Xampp version and copy "php_curl.dll" from the php folder to my old php folder (replacing the old dll.) and, of course, restart Apache. If the php_curl version is very new the dll is not going to work (Xampp configurations problems) so is important to use only the next version.